# How to add and remove active class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How  can i change class .active-link when i click on other anchors?

```
 <div id="settings" class="account-collapse collapse in">
     <div class="account-body">
    <a href="#/PersonalInfo" class="active-link">PERSONAL_INFORMATION</a>
    <a href="#/Notifications">NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS</a>
    <a href="#/PasswordChange">CHANGE_PASSWORD</a>
    <a href="#">GAME_SETTINGS</a>
     </div>
     </div>
```

I tried this but its not working:

```
    $('div').click(function () {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        $("a.active-link").removeClass();
        $('a[href="' + hash + '"]').addClass('active-link');


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('#settings a').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault(); // prevent default action
   $('#settings a').removeClass('active-link'); // remove all active class
   $(this).addClass('active-link'); // apply for current a tag
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/45z8qdq3/)

Comment: when i used your part of code here http://jsfiddle.net/uzhas/t18ugs6y/ its not working ??

Comment: I just include jquery in left hand side in dropdown

Comment: its working on jsfiddle but from some reason its not working on my page :S

Comment: Then what can i do . Please make sure your jquery is included and working

Comment: you have get some idea from code means please put upvote and accept my answer otherwise raise another question anybody answer you

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#settings a').not('.active-link').click(function(){//when other links are clicked
    $('#settings .active-link').removeClass('active-link').addClass('mynewclass');
})
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/fuk4cyk4/2/